# UnsatisfiedLinkError in non-updated bundle when updating a client bundle

Tags: java, osgi

I have a bundle ("`com.elsten.bliss.platform`") that uses another bundle ("`net.contentobjects.jnotify`"). `net.contentobjects.jnotify` loads native libraries to do its job, which are contributed by fragments. The native code is loaded in a static class initializer inside a class within the `net.contentobjects.jnotify` bundle:

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("jnotify");
    int res = nativeInit();
    if (res != 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing fshook_inotify library. linux error code #" + res  + ", man errno for more info");
    }
    init();
}
```

I can start and stop `com.elsten.bliss.platform` and it appears to work ok. The problem comes when updating `com.elsten.bliss.platform`. When I update, I get:

```
2013-04-04 11:58:20,356 [ERROR]  Couldn't initialise JNotify: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /home/gravelld/eclipse-workspaces/bliss/net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.amd64/lib/libjnotify.so already loaded in another classloader (JnotifyFileSystemObserver.java:53, thread platformExecutor)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library /home/gravelld/eclipse-workspaces/bliss/net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.amd64/lib/libjnotify.so already loaded in another classloader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1715)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotify_linux.<clinit>(JNotify_linux.java:48)
    at net.contentobjects.jnotify.linux.JNotifyAdapterLinux.<init>(JNotifyAdapterLinux.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:374)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify.<clinit>(JNotify.java:75)
    at com.elsten.bliss.platform.storage.file.JnotifyFileSystemObserver.startWatching(JnotifyFileSystemObserver.java:43)
    at com.elsten.bliss.platform.storage.file.NotifyFilesAtStartFileSystemObserver.start(NotifyFilesAtStartFileSystemObserver.java:117)
    at com.elsten.bliss.platform2.PlumbedStorageSubsystem.start(PlumbedStorageSubsystem.java:69)
    at com.elsten.bliss.client.impl.ConfigurationClientImpl$3.doRun(ConfigurationClientImpl.java:337)
    at com.elsten.util.CatchThrowableRunnable.run(CatchThrowableRunnable.java:23)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Ok, so I know you can only have any one native library loaded by one classloader. But in this case, why is there more than one class loader? The `net.contentobjects.jnotify` is not updated, so I thought the existing classes should just continue on and be used by `JnotifyFileSystemObserver.startWatching` - it appears this method is reloading the class.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, that code if called twice should not raise an exception; the javadoc for `java.lang.Runtime#loadLibrary()` states that

> If this method is called more than once with the same library name, the second and subsequent calls are ignored.

So, there might be more to it. Have you tried setting the singleton property in the Bundle-SymbolicName entry of the MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: Just tried it... that appears to work in that there's no error message. My file notifications are still not working but I think that must be a different problem. Any more guidance as to what this directive does other than http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-SymbolicName ?

Comment: By default, there can be multiple instances of a bundle installed & running in an OSGi system/framework/container, f.e. if there are multiple versions of one. This property indicates that a bundle is a singleton, i.e. there can be only one *active* at any one time. There can be others installed, but there can be only one active.

Comment: I assumed the library would be identified by its absolute filesystem name, or similar... so different versions would have different paths and multiple files would be loaded as native libraries. Maybe it's just the libx.so name?

Comment: That is actually implementation-dependent. However, it may try to load the same name from two different files, hence this error...